# Certificate error in Skype: pmpubs

Tags: skype, certificate

Yesterday while using Windows 8.1 and Skype, suddenly Certificate warnings, issued for the web page "pmpubs.com", certified from `go daddy secure` came up, and the onliest thing I could do was to allow them. My initial reaction was (thinking of a virus) a hard shut down, in order to prevent damage.
Until now I could not find anything about the web page mentioned above (except an empty page), and no further information if that is a legitime warning or malicious. AV-Scanner did not alarm me. Backup is done. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have encountered these issues on various PCs as well. Searching around, there are 4 possible actions proposed in various places:

1) Delete all temporary internet files from the Internet Explorer cache. (Independently of the browser your are using for surfing).

2) Delete the Internet Explorer history files.

3) Empty the Skype cache (/%appdata%/Skype/DBTemp)

4) Block access to the domains is question by adding them to the 'hosts' file.

This one did the trick for me, but it addresses only the symptoms, it's 'dirty' and it's very like only a temporary solution as new sites with certificate issues may appear in the Skype Ad distribution network.

```
/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
```

Add:

```
127.0.0.1      problemdomain1.com
127.0.0.1      problemdomain2.com
```

The domain names are obtained by displaying the certificate properties that are making Skype popping up the warnings.

---

Note: I'm aware that this does not fix the root cause and that it may be of temporary help only. But at least, you can get Skype unblocked.